# Erro ao tentar reinstalar Python

Tags: python-3.x

Meu Python era instalado na partição "D:" (em um HD normal) eo meu SO na "C:" (em um SSD). Movi o SDD (Partição "C:") do meu antigo computador para um novo e tentei reinstalar o python nele, porém recebo uma mensagem que ele está instalado na partição "D:", que existe, mas agora é um driver de CD/DVD.

[image: esse erro acontece nos três processos: reparo, modificação e remoção]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma verificada, seu computador pode ser 64-bit e isso aí é para 32-bits

Comment: Verdade, consegui utilizando o instalador de 64-bits. Eu só não entendi pq não posso usar um 32-bits, acho que a versão anterior era 32-bits.

Comment: Possívelmente! Se possível, marca a resposta como a correta! Abraços!